# ontouch on frame by frame animation

Tags: android, imageview

How to implement on touch on  image view which is used for frame by frame animation...
I am using this as follow

```
 final AnimationDrawable newtonAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) animation.getBackground();

           AnimationStart(newtonAnimation);

            animation.setOnTouchListener(l);


public void AnimationStart(final AnimationDrawable newanimation){
    Thread timer=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
                            try{
                                    sleep(40);
                                }catch(Exception e){}
                                finally{
                                            Newton_LawsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                public void run(){
                                                newanimation.start();
                                            }});
                                        }
                            }
                        };
    timer.start();
```

}
  This is where i am getting the ontouch event .......

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("debug","nullis event"+event+"OR"+gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event));

        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: what is AnimationStart(newtonAnimation)?

Comment: is this method do the animation functionality?

Comment: I am editing my question check that ....

Answer (score 0):

set ontouch lintener like below

```
             animation.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                    {
                        newtonAnimation.stop(); 
                        Toast.makeText(FrameAnimationActivity.this, "animation stoped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return false;
                    }
            });
```

Comment: can you explain me Toast.makeText(FrameAnimationActivity.this, "animation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Toast is just for testing Touch event, you can put your code instead of Toast  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: FrameAnimationActivity.this is the Context of your Activity

Comment: if i want to return the gesture dtectore then \

Comment: why you want and where you create the object of GestureDetector?

Comment: I have intialized in  starting ...and returning during ontouch event

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12152/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-srivastava-and-ashishsingh)